# Is "Take note of ___ into account" proper usage?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Is this sentence correct, with "take note of" and "into account" referring to the same thing?

> Please take note of the sales prices into account in any future preliminary or suggested price to any third party.

My boss dictated this to me, and I can't figure out exactly what it is... But it sounds wrong.  Redundancy, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

"take note of" and "into account" mean the same thing. To attach the two phrases to the same noun phrase, "sales prices," is, as you thought, redundant.

Comment: +1, but just to make your answer a bit clearer:  "Please take the sales prices into account in any future preliminary or suggested price to any third party"  or  "Please note the sales prices in any future preliminary or suggested price to any third party."